# How can I list all package versions from yarn.lock file in yarn3.x?

Tags: package.json, yarnpkg-v3, yarn-v3

I have several 'latest' and '^x.x.x' packages for a package that's going into maintenance mode. For stability purposes, I'd like to fix all package versions.

After spending some time combing through the yarn.lock file, I noticed multiple versions of individual packages, making this process very cumbersome.

Most other answers refer to a specific package, using `yarn list`, which doesn't apply to v3+ and `yarn why`, which applies to individual packages.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the documentation over at https://yarnpkg.com/ to be particularly helpful (largely down to the UX) but I found the following through `yarn help`:

```
yarn info -A --name-only
```

This prints the name of each package, accompanied by the npm version. This wasn't tested but may also work for yarn2.x

Comment: To install the package versions found in yarn.lock, use `yarn install --immutable`